# widget crashes on rotation, vertical to horizontal

Tags: android, crash, widget, imagebutton

Good day.
I have a Widget with image button.
I'm trying to set an image on a button using the following code but my widget crashes on rotation! Do you have any ideas?

```
  @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
       RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
       remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageButton, MyNewimageID);

       ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class);
       AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
       manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
     }
```

Comment: Please post the error stack.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution

```
Intent active = new Intent(context, MyWidget.class);
active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);       remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imagebuttonButton, actionPendingIntent);
manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```